# Why can't I push back changes to Git Windows server?

Tags: git

I have two Windows machines to work with the same code repository. And for my convenience, I use one for Git server temporary, and clone code in the other machine. When changes has done, I will push the change back.

I start the git server by following command in Git Bash under Windows:

```
$ git daemon --base-path=E:/MyCode/ --export-all --enable=receive-pack
```

But when I push back the changes from the other machine, there is nothing happened. The other machine is just on the uploading UI for a lot time until I shut it down.

On server side, Git Bash shows an error message when I shut the push operation down:

> [2944] fatal: write error: Invalid argument

Why? How can I push changes back?

Answer (score 0):

The `base-path` looks suspicious to me. Should it not be `/e/MyCode` in bash?

Comment: I think the base-path is OK, because I can clone in the other machine. BTW, I changed the base-path to your style, the problem is still there.